# Visual Studio 2015 CTP - Javascript support missing

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I had Visual Studio 2015 CTP 4 installed and now CTP6 - In both cases it was missing Javascript support.

- Not showing syntax highlighting for .js file
- Intellisense  not working for .js files

Also when i go to tools/options/Text Editor - Javascript language section is missing. See  image and its comparison with VS2013.

Image At: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/615484

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a little late but this fixed the issue for me. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f3693b97-7fb1-4b9a-9953-1970b767a407/visual-studio-2015-ctp-javascript-support-missing?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: I think he/she must mean the section that references https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025135. Go to that link and search for Cordova and JavaScript and then do the instructions in the section: Workaround. That fixed the problem for me!

Answer (score 3):

To expand on what @user3810312 said...

1. If you installed to another drive, copy your `C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio 14.0` folder on top of your install.
2. Open the Visual Studio Command prompt as an administrator (right-click run as Administrator)
3. Navigate to the directory where VS 2015 is installed
4. Run `devenv /setup`
5. Run `devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates`

I had Intellisense the next time I booted up Visual Studio 2015. Worked like a charm.