# VS 2015: No highlighting and intellisense in JS files

Tags: javascript, ide, syntax-highlighting, intellisense, visual-studio-2015

I can't really reproduce the issue, but no highlighting or intellisense is working in `.js` files, it works just fine in `.json` files however.
The default editor for `.js` files is JSON Editor.

I tried safe-mode, disabling all extensions, resetting all settings, and I even reinstalled the IDE (repair), but the issue still persists.

I will add, that when I launch the IDE and a JS file is open on scope, I get the following error message (highlighting and intellisense don't work anyway):

> The 'JavaScriptWebExtensionPackage' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information examining the file 'C:\Users\Shimmy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml'.
>
> Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve the issue.
>
> Continue to show this error message?

[Here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4DizyM4S) you can view the *ActivityLog.xml* file, I pasted in some of the recent lines I think might be relevant:

```
<entry>
  <record>188</record>
  <time>2015/08/14 13:00:57.332</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Begin package load [JavaScriptWebExtensionsPackage]</description>
  <guid>{30DB8F9B-EC9F-44D6-B377-83C7C27A1A8B}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>189</record>
  <time>2015/08/14 13:00:57.394</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>SetSite failed for package [JavaScriptWebExtensionsPackage]</description>
  <guid>{30DB8F9B-EC9F-44D6-B377-83C7C27A1A8B}</guid>
  <hr>80131500</hr>
  <errorinfo>Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.ReferenceAutoSync.IReferencesFilePathProvider" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.</errorinfo>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>190</record>
  <time>2015/08/14 13:00:57.394</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>End package load [JavaScriptWebExtensionsPackage]</description>
  <guid>{30DB8F9B-EC9F-44D6-B377-83C7C27A1A8B}</guid>
  <hr>80131500</hr>
  <errorinfo>Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.ReferenceAutoSync.IReferencesFilePathProvider" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.</errorinfo>
</entry>
```

Comment: [This question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772224/visual-studio-2017-rtm-javascript-intellisense-not-working) might be helpful in this matter as well.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found answer here: [Visual Studio 2015 RTM - Lost JavaScript support after update TypeSript Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888115/visual-studio-2015-rtm-lost-javascript-support-after-update-typesript-tools)

These are the steps to fix it:

> If the “Universal Windows App Development Tools” are still installed:
>
> 1. Go to Programs and Features, select Visual Studio 2015, click Change.
> 2. In Visual Studio setup, click Modify.
> 3. Deselect the feature “Universal Windows App Development Tools”
> 4. Select “Universal Windows App Development Tools” again, and click Update.
>
> If you have already uninstalled the “Universal Windows App Development Tools”:
>
> - Reinstall “Universal Windows App Development Tools”
> - Or, take the following steps to reinstall the JavaScript project system and language service:
>
>   1. Download the installer for your edition of Visual Studio, e.g., vs_community.exe.
>   2. Open a CMD window, and run the following command: vs_community.exe /modify /installselectableitems JavaScript_Hidden /passive

I've followed the first steps and got back Javascript support.

Hope this helps

**-UPDATED-**

After I did the above steps, almost everything was working, except that I got an error message every time I opened a .js file, the following did the trick:

My guess is that only reinstalling the SDK didn't update the MEF cache. You can do this manually by following these steps:

> Open a command prompt as administrator
>
> 1. CD into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>      14.0\Common7\IDE
> 2. Run devenv /updateconfiguration
> 3. Run devenv /clearcache

That got rid of the last error, and everything is working fine.

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4238

Comment: Very helpful and comprehensive! Thanks for your effort. That solved all the issues and the error is gone.

Comment: That resolved my problem, thank you so much been without JS support for 2 weeks, was starting to annoy me to no end.

Comment: Same symptoms, same fix!  Thanks for the write-up!

Comment: Didn't work for me in Visual Studio 2017, unfortunately.  (Followed the steps but still no syntax highlighting in .js files when I was finished.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be fixed on Update 1. I'm on the professional version but I imagine that it applies to all versions.

To be clear, Intellisense was not working for me for css related stuff on razor files and post update 1 it seems to be working.

Comment: I have Update 2 and ran into same issue, so it wasn't fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is clearly targeting Visual Studio 2015.

However, I wanted to put my two cents in for those who desperately tried out if the accepted answer also works for **Visual Studio 2017**.

In my case, the loss of syntax highlighting was caused by the new javascript language service. I got it back right after deselecting the following checkbox and restarting Visual Studio:

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Language
>   Service > Enable the new JavaScript language service.*

*Reference: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/34109/view.html*