# Visual Studio 2015 - Javascript intellisense stopped working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I'm using **Visual Studio 2015** and the javascript intellisense was working fine. A little while later, I opened a `.js` file and there was no IntelliSense nor color anymore.

- I've restarted VS
- Rebooted my machine
- Deleted and re-added a .js file

No luck... Is this a Bug? Has anyone experienced the same?

The `javascript` is working when I run the site, and I can edit the files, but it's frustrating as it feels like working in `NotePad`. See image below :\

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000562/vs-2015-no-highlighting-and-intellisense-in-js-files

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much @epascarello