# VisualStudio Code javascript intellisense and colored-text not working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When I opened VisualStudio Code today the javascript in my files no longer had colored-text. All javascript shows as only white text. ie) a string should show as red, and a declared variabled as blue, etc..

How do I turn these features back on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000562/vs-2015-no-highlighting-and-intellisense-in-js-files

Comment: Is Code correctly associating your files with JavaScript? Do you see "JavaScript" listed in the bottom right hand of the window? See this page to make sure: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/overview