# Can't Create nor Open Apache Cordova Projects Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

When I try to open or Create a new Apache Cordova Project the IDE just stop to respond. I found inside the ActivityLog.xml some errors related to Apache Cordova Extension Initialization:

> VisualStudio 2015/08/17 13:40:36.261 
>   728 Begin package load [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage] {317A330D-8757-4084-8526->E8A1D165433D} VisualStudio 2015/08/17 13:40:36.261 
>   729 ERROR SetSite failed for package [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage] {317A330D-8757-4084-8526->E8A1D165433D} 80131604 VisualStudio 2015/08/17 13:40:36.498 
>   730 ERROR End package load [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage] {317A330D-8757-4084-8526->E8A1D165433D} 80131604 VisualStudio 2015/08/17 13:40:36.503 
>   731 Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {317A330D-8757-4084-8526->E8A1D165433D} VisualStudio 2015/08/17 13:40:48.902 
>   732 Begin package load [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage] {317A330D-8757-4084-8526->E8A1D165433D} VisualStudio 2015/08/17 13:40:48.902 
>   733 ERROR SetSite failed for package [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage] {317A330D-8757-4084-8526->E8A1D165433D} 80131604 VisualStudio 2015/08/17 13:40:48.903 
>   734 ERROR End package load [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage]

I had a clean instalation, and just upgraded the VS 2015 Azure SDK, nothing else more, but somehow stop working.

I opened an issue at Cordova GitHub as well: [Can't Create nor Open Apache Cordova Projects #26](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/issues/26)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for your trouble. This is a known issue which we have fixed for new installs, but some customers will run into the problem depending on when they installed the win10 tools.

Can you please follow the steps I outlined this answer?

[Visual Studio 2015 RTM - Lost JavaScript support after update TypeSript Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888115/visual-studio-2015-rtm-lost-javascript-support-after-update-typesript-tools/31899415#31899415)

Although that post is about typescript, it is the same problem and the same steps will unblock you.

Comment: This solved half of the issue, now I have a missing Run Parameters like Ripple! How can I solve that?

Comment: Can you try these steps:

1. Open a command prompt as administrator.
2. CD to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
3. run devenv /updateconfiguration
4. run devenv /clearcache

Answer (score 1):

this steps working with me:

1. Open a command prompt as administrator
2. CD to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
3. run devenv /updateconfiguration
4. run devenv /clearcache

Re-write (@Michael Braude) comment, thank you very much