# Visual Studio javascript intellisense is completely missing

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, intellisense

When I'm editing some .js file in Visual Studio I don't have any of these features:

https://webtooling.visualstudio.com/languages/javascript/

I already tried:

1 - Start visual studio in /SafeMode.

2 - Uncheck/Check the option "Auto list members" on "Tools > Options > Text Editor > Javascript".

3 - The solution described here:
[Visual Studio 2015 RTM - Lost JavaScript support after update TypeSript Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888115/visual-studio-2015-rtm-lost-javascript-support-after-update-typesript-tools)

4 - Uninstall/Install Visual Studio (I tried twice).

None of these brought back the intellisense support for JavaScript.

Currently (until I find a solution), I'm working with Visual Studio Code for JavaScript files.

Anyone had these problems too and managed to solve it?

Software Details: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015, Version: 14.0.25425.01 Update 3.

Comment: really not trying to be that guy, you sound like you have this under control, but have you tried turning your computer off and on again?

Comment: @Matthias yes, twice. =D

Comment: Well @AlexandrePerez you just saved me from trying that. This is mind blowing, and seriously frustrating since the next step in my project was to start working on and writing JavaScript code. Like the idea of VSCode as a substitute! Although part of me, out of spite, wants to use anything but Microsoft for the JS code right now >.<

Comment: @Bwolfing The problem seems to be related to _references.js file. After delete it, the intellisense started work again. If I recreate the _references.js, the intellisense stop work. Weird don't? Anyway, delete your _references.js and see if works.

Comment: .....I am going to set VS15 on fire. I cannot believe that fixed the issue. Regardless, thank you @AlexandrePerez

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while back with a relatively new .js. I just manually added the lib's as well as through NPM and it seemed to work. Since then I just do both as a precaution.