# Visual studio 2015 missing option: Tools-Options-Text editor->Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2015

with VS 2015 community update 1 I need to configure angular/javascript by menu Tools-Options-Text editor->Javascript

in VS2013 U5 option is ok
[image]
but in 2015 Update 1 there is not
[image]
thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Community and I have all of the languages listed.

Comment: Looks like something went wrong with the update. Try repairing Visual Studio from the Programs and Features screen of windows.

Comment: tried repair,reinstall....no fix, VS version is 14.0.24720.00

Comment: Maybe related: [Visual Studio 2015 CTP - Javascript support missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704964/visual-studio-2015-ctp-javascript-support-missing)

Comment: seems that update 1 was the problem:i've reinstalled the system,menu got back but extensions like Web essential not working propely,I decided to go back to VS with no update,all works now. THANKS TO ALL!

Comment: I make it also working with update 1,I run VS 'as administrator' on extensions install and seems to work